# Cycle fadeIn and fadeOut between 2 images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took a look at some answers already posted but didn't find the correct way to do this.
I have 2 images in the same `div`, one is visible the other is set to `display:none;`
I want a non-ending loop between the 2 images, with the fade-out/fade-in effects, **without any jQuery plugin**.

I think, it's just a few lines of code.

Comment: i am probably missing the point but, have you considered an animated gif

Comment: @Joseph: Maybe he just does not want to use any further jQuery plugins. jQuery is not a plugin, it is a library.

Comment: I see... sorry. fixed. :S ty, Felix

Comment: jquery is a framework not a plugin, I want to achive this via jquery because I think is the best way but without using additional JQUERY's plugins.
@bugstylee yes I have consider it but it's not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elegant yet simple way:

```js
function fadeShow(fadeTime, fadeDelay) {
  var $topImage = $("#fadeBox img:last");
  $topImage.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0, function() {
    $topImage.fadeTo(fadeDelay, 0, function() {
      $topImage.fadeTo(0, 1);
      $topImage.insertBefore("#fadeBox img:first");
      fadeShow(fadeTime, fadeDelay);
    });
  });
}

fadeShow(2000, 5000);
```

```css
#fadeBox {
  position: relative;
}

#fadeBox img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadeBox">
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vp16kljkPwg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAKg/Ypz8rdBRFjQ/s200-c/photo.jpg">
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uQqDiQ92aZQ/TiZspaC99wI/AAAAAAAAAFE/KZU_RIKUfTI/s200-c/photo.jpg">
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvPXM/)

Supports multiple images but they must all be the same size.
have fun. :)

Comment: I like this solution, but I'm using images with trasparent background. I don't know if this matters but I have some problems.This is what I got:
- the first image is visible
- after some times the second image just appear clearly under the first
- the first image begin to fadeout
- after some times, the first images comes up clearly without fadeing, and the other begins to fadeout

what's the problem?

Comment: I figure out that is for thew trasparency images...how to edit this beautiful script for trasparency?

Comment: ok. I think I see what you're seeing. Something to the effect of this? http://jsfiddle.net/PvPXM/3/ Unfortunately, that jumpy side effect has to be there, but there is a simple way around it.  You could just fake it by duplicating the images like so: http://jsfiddle.net/PvPXM/4/

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick and dirty solution but maybe it could help you get an idea of how to tackle your problem...

```
function swap ( $img1 , $img2, speed ) {
    $img1.stop().fadeOut(speed);
    $img2.stop().fadeIn(speed);

    setTimeout( function () { swap( $img2, $img1, speed) }, speed );
};
```

Comment: @Kreker. Yes it is.. It's recursively infinite. You don't need a `for` or `while` statement to have a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var blink_data={};
function start_blink(id)
{
    blink_data={subj:document.getElementById(id),duration_in:600,duration_sus:400,time_in:new Date,proc_in:function(){
        var c=new Date;
        var d=(c.getTime() - blink_data.time_in.getTime())/blink_data.duration_in;
        if(d>1){
            d=1;
            clearInterval(blink_data.interval);
            blink_data.interval=null;
            blink_data.timeout=setTimeout(function(){
                blink_data.interval=setInterval(blink_data.proc_out,50);
                blink_data.time_out=new Date;
                blink_data.timeout=null;
            },blink_data.duration_sus);
        }


        blink_data.subj.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+d*100+")";
        blink_data.subj.style.opacity=d;

    },duration_out:600,time_out:new Date,proc_out:function(){
        var c=new Date;
        var d=(c.getTime() - blink_data.time_out.getTime())/blink_data.duration_out;
        if(d>1){
            d=1;
            clearInterval(blink_data.interval);
            blink_data.interval=null;
            blink_data.timeout=setTimeout(function(){
                blink_data.interval=setInterval(blink_data.proc_in,50);
                blink_data.time_in=new Date;
                blink_data.timeout=null;
            },blink_data.duration_sus);
        }

        d=1 - d;
        blink_data.subj.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+d*100+")";
        blink_data.subj.style.opacity=d;

    },timeout:null,interval:null};
    blink_data.interval=setInterval(blink_data.proc_in,50);
}

function stop_blink()
{
    if(blink_data.timeout){
        clearTimeout(blink_data.timeout);
    } else if(blink_data.interval){
        clearInterval(blink_data.interval);
    }
    blink_data.subj.style.filter="alpha(opacity=0)";
    blink_data.subj.style.opacity=0;
}
```

You only have to fadein/out one image (if you're not using transparent images) and let the image on top fade in and out. (And remove the display:none style)

if you have a structure like this:

```
<div>
<img id='img1' src='path/to/image.jpg'/>
<img id='img2' src='path/to/image2.jpg'/>
</div>
```

call the function with

```
start_blink('img2');
```

Comment: I don't think this works, I don't want that the 2 images were displayed at the same time. The first must be visible, fadeing out, and fadeing in the other one, again fadeout this and fade in the previuos one....and infinite loop

Comment: It works .. trust me: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/jCDBe/](http://jsfiddle.net/jCDBe/)
If you care about performance, you don't want 2 images fading at the same time ..

Answer (score 0):

Say your html is :

```
<div>
    <img src="..." id="img1"/>
    <img src="..." id="img2"/>    
</div>
```

Your JavaScript can be something like that :

```
fadeOutIn('#img1', '#img2');



function fadeOutIn(elmt1, elmt2){
    alert("1");
    $(elmt1).fadeOut(1, function(){

        $(elmt2).fadeIn(1, function(){
            //add a time out here if you want the image to stay for a while before fading
            fadeInOut(elmt2, elmt1);
        }):

    });   
}
```

That is if you want the fade out and fade in to happen separately, if you want them to happen concurrently then call them at the same time like in Greg's answer.